# How to change JsonObject in JsonArray?

Tags: java, json

I'm using `javax.json` and when I tried change `jsonObject` in my `jsonArray`:

```
String jsonString = "[{\"name\":\"xyz\"," +
                        "\"URL\":\"http://example.com\"}]";
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonReader.readArray();

String jsonNewString = "{\"name\":\"zyx\","
                         + "\"URL\":\"http://example2.com\"}]";   
jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonNewString));
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();

jsonArray.remove(0);
jsonArray.add(0, jsonObject);
```

I got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
```

I also tried:  `jsonArray.set(0, jsonObject);`, and got the same `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc of [`JsonArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) states

> `JsonArray` represents an immutable JSON array (an ordered sequence of
>   zero or more values). **It also provides an unmodifiable list view of
>   the values in the array.**

You can't change it. Create a new one with the value(s) you want.

Answer (score 0):

**JsonObject and JsonArray are immutable** so you cannot modify the object , you can use this example and try to inspire from it :

creation of a new JsonObject who contains the same values and add some elements to it ..

**Example :**

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import javax.json.Json;
    import javax.json.JsonArray;
    import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
    import javax.json.JsonObject;
    import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;
    import javax.json.JsonReader;
    import javax.json.JsonValue;


    public class Jsonizer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    String s = "{\"persons\": [ {\"name\":\"oussama\",\"age\":\"30\"}, {\"name\":\"amine\",\"age\":\"25\"} ]}";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
    JsonReader jr = Json.createReader(is);
    JsonObject jo = jr.readObject();
    System.out.println("Before :");
    System.out.println(jo);
    JsonArray ja = jo.getJsonArray("persons");

    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("{\"name\":\"sami\",\"age\":\"50\"}".getBytes());
    jr = Json.createReader(targetStream);
    JsonObject newJo = jr.readObject();
    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArraybuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    jsonArraybuilder.add(newJo);
    
    for (JsonValue jValue : ja) {
        jsonArraybuilder.add(jValue);
    }
    
    ja = jsonArraybuilder.build();
    JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    jsonObjectBuilder.add("persons", ja);
    JsonObject jsonAfterAdd = jsonObjectBuilder.build();
    System.out.println("After");
    System.out.println(jsonAfterAdd.toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

**Output :**

```
     Before :
     {"persons":[{"name":"oussama","age":"30"},{"name":"amine","age":"25"}]}
     After
     {"persons":[{"name":"sami","age":"50"},{"name":"oussama","age":"30"},{"name":"amine","age":"25"}]}
```